# Remove quotes if "=" (equal) sign exists in the middle of the string. REGEX

Tags: r, regex

In this string the character “=” differentiates attributes for a product, and commas distinguish variables within an attribute. However, we found that sometimes extra quotes have been added when there are no variables to put together.

The complete string is :

Uso="Protector para patas de silla,mesas,escaleras,muebles","Topes,4-Tipo=Topes,regatones",2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,regatones,7-Contenido="12 unidades,4-Origen=China,4-Material=Goma,2-Modelo=Goma transparente,9-Incluye=12 unidades,3-Color=Transparente"

**This is right:**

```
Uso="Protector para patas de silla,mesas,escaleras,muebles"
```

**This is wrong:**

```
"Topes,4-Tipo=Topes,regatones",2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,regatones,7-Contenido="12 unidades,4-Origen=China,4-Material=Goma,2-Modelo=Goma transparente,9-Incluye=12 unidades,3-Color=Transparente"

 Categoría="Topes,4-Tipo=Topes,regatones",2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,regatones,7-Contenido="12 unidades,4-Origen=China,4-Material=Goma,2-Modelo=Goma transparente,9-Incluye=12 unidades,3-Color=Transparente"
```

I´ve tried `"|w+="` but selects all quotes. I don´t want to select text between quotes, the goal is select and remove these quotes.

We want to remove those quotes that contains an equal in between. The quotes that are ok and need to stay are those used to separate commas within the string, differentiating the variables from the string.

The regex needs to detect an = contained into and opening and closing quotes, but considering text in between. And once this is detected remove those quotes, which no need to be there.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you format your question and give your sample code in valid R syntax? I can't tell where line breaks are supposed to be, what data structure you're using, is it all one big string or multiple little strings...

Comment: Try [`gsub('"([^"=]*=[^"]*)"', '\\1', x)`](https://ideone.com/EEZ41E)

Comment: So, does `cat(gsub('"([^"=]*=[^"]*)"', '\\1', x))` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew selects text between text too, we only need select quotes

Comment: But you want to remove the quotes, right? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Nico-Párraga just curious- in the wrong cases you don't want to place new  quotes after the `=`, just remove them completely?

Comment: the thing is that we have extra quotes. The pair of quotes which is right are those that contains commas to separate variables. The ones we need to remove are those which contains an equal in the middle. The logic would be "if we find a sentence with an opening and closing quotes, which contain an =, we need to remove those quotes". Does it make sense?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/EEZ41E solution and let know if it works.

Comment: INPUT x <- '10-Uso="Protector para patas de silla,mesas,escaleras,muebles",6-Características=Regaton interior 1 1/4 plástico blanco 4 unidades,1-Marca=Nagel,Tipo=Topes,5-Medidas=3 cm,3-Categoría=Topes y regatones,7-Contenido=4 unidades,4-Tipo=Regatones,2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,9-Incluye=4 regatones plásticos,regatones,4-Origen="Argentina,4-Material=Plástico,2-Modelo=Regatón interior 1 1/4,3-Color=Blanco"'

Comment: OUTPUT 10-Uso="Protector para patas de silla,mesas,escaleras,muebles,6-Características=Regaton interior 1 1/4 plástico blanco 4 unidades,1-Marca=Nagel,Tipo=Topes,5-Medidas=3 cm,3-Categoría=Topes y regatones,7-Contenido=4 unidades,4-Tipo=Regatones,2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,9-Incluye=4 regatones plásticos,regatones,4-Origen=Argentina,4-Material=Plástico,2-Modelo=Regatón interior 1 1/4,3-Color=Blanco"

Comment: Please note that quote after muebles need to be kept and quote after blanco needs to be removed

Comment: Please add it to the question keeping correct formatting.

Comment: Try [`cat(gsub('="([^"=]*=[^"]*)"', '=\\1', x))`](https://ideone.com/NSQRj2). Do I get it right there must always be `=` right before these quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the quoted substring should be preceded with `=`. Then, you need

```
gsub('="([^"=]*=[^"]*)"', '=\\1', x)
```

See the R [demo online](https://ideone.com/NSQRj2):

```
x <- '10-Uso="Protector para patas de silla,mesas,escaleras,muebles",6-Características=Regaton interior 1 1/4 plástico blanco 4 unidades,1-Marca=Nagel,Tipo=Topes,5-Medidas=3 cm,3-Categoría=Topes y regatones,7-Contenido=4 unidades,4-Tipo=Regatones,2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,9-Incluye=4 regatones plásticos,regatones,4-Origen="Argentina,4-Material=Plástico,2-Modelo=Regatón interior 1 1/4,3-Color=Blanco"'
cat(gsub('="([^"=]*=[^"]*)"', '=\\1', x))
## => 10-Uso="Protector para patas de silla,mesas,escaleras,muebles",6-Características=Regaton interior 1 1/4 plástico blanco 4 unidades,1-Marca=Nagel,Tipo=Topes,5-Medidas=3 cm,3-Categoría=Topes y regatones,7-Contenido=4 unidades,4-Tipo=Regatones,2-Familia=Ferretería y Plomería,9-Incluye=4 regatones plásticos,regatones,4-Origen=Argentina,4-Material=Plástico,2-Modelo=Regatón interior 1 1/4,3-Color=Blanco
```

So, the quote after `muebles` is kept and quote after `blanco` is removed.

How does this work?

- `="` - matches `="` substring
- `([^"=]*=[^"]*)` - matches and captures into Group 1:

  - `[^"=]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `=`
  - `=` - a `=` sign
  - `[^"]*` - any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - matches `"`.

The replacement pattern is a `=` and the value stored in Group 1 memory buffer (`\1`, a replacement backreference).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/In6Y7t/1).

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks